# MVC4 and MVCContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvccontrib

Does MVCContrib currently support MVC4?  I am having a first look at switching a project from MVC2 to MVC4 and having some issues with Portable Areas.

Comment: _Shooh, short answer: "Yes" with an "If," long answer: "No" -- with a "But."_ ([Rev. Lovejoy, The Simpsons](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/4F07.html))

Looks like it's somewhat do-able, but there are a few gotchas. Have you seen [this article](http://ivanz.com/2012/08/20/guide-for-migrating-an-asp-net-mvc-solution-to-net-4-5-and-asp-net-mvc-4/)? We're just getting into MvcContrib for the grid and other controls on our greenfield MVC4/.NET4.5 application, so we'll see how it goes.

Comment: here is an working example of it with MVC 4
https://github.com/codedjungle/MvcContrib

Answer (score 17):

In case anyone else comes across this post, you could try these:

http://nuget.org/packages/StudioDonder.MvcContrib.Mvc4/
http://nuget.org/packages/StudioDonder.MvcContrib.Mvc4.TestHelper/
etc.

with the source here: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/ErikSchierboom/mvccontribmvc4

For each, they say:
Note: this is a fork of the MvcContrib project that is suited for working with ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 3):

I can say from experience that it "sort of" works.

I'm working on a project where we were using the Mvc.Contrib.TestHelpers assembly, and in that case, I had to download the source code from Codeplex, update the MVC references from version 3 to version 4 and rebuild the project, then reference my rebuilt version of MvcContrib.

I hope that helps :)